# glob.iglob results ordered by name?

Tags: python, sorting, directory, glob

I need to iterate through a potentially ***very*** large directory (arbitrarily large). From what I understand, the regular `glob.glob` function stores a list of *all* the matching filenames in memory, but the `glob.iglob` function uses an iterator. So using the regular `glob.glob` function is out of the question, since there may be A ***lot*** of files in the directory.

My problem is that `iglob` iterates through the directory in a seemingly random order. I would like it to iterate through the files in alphabetical order. I cannot get a list of all the filenames at once, and just sort them, so I am wondering if there is a way to make `iglob` iterate through the directory in alphabetical order.

Comment: How many is `A LOT`? A modern computer shouldn't have any problems with keeping millions of filenames in memory.

Answer (score 9):

No, there isn't, not without reading all the contents of the directory into memory. The operating system provides the filenames in directory order, and would need to read the contents into memory in full as well if it wanted to sort these.

You could sort the results after `iglob()` matched files, provided that set is small enough to fit into memory by calling `sorted()` on the `iglob()` output:

```
for filename in sorted(iglob(path)):
```

Note that `iglob()` already [loads all entries of a single directory into a list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e7c495e32cb22a5334a75d5b0e848a8cd752717e/Lib/glob.py#L81-L85) when not recursing to subdirectories (partly because [`fnmatch()` returns a list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e7c495e32cb22a5334a75d5b0e848a8cd752717e/Lib/fnmatch.py#L48-L62)).

Comment: and sorted on iglob will exhaust the iterator by fetching everything into memory..

Comment: @Vadim: If an iterator is needed, you can always do `iter(sorted(iglob(path)))` to get one (although that will still read all the names into memory because that's necessary to be able to sort them).

Comment: There's no advantage here to use `iglob` over simply `glob`. Probably `glob` is a better choice.

Comment: @ingyhere: exactly, as noted in my answer. The OP asked for `iglob()`, but there is no point here.

Answer (score 2):

From the `glob` module's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

> The `glob` module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
>   according to the rules used by the Unix shell. No tilde expansion is
>   done, but `*`, `?`, and character ranges expressed with `[]` will be
>   correctly matched. **This is done by using the `os.listdir()`** and
>   `fnmatch.fnmatch()` functions in concert, and not by actually invoking a
>   subshell.

And if we look the documentation for `os.listdir`:

> os.listdir(path)
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.
>   **The list is in arbitrary order**. It does not include the
>   special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.

So `glob.glob` does not return the files in alphabetical order. It is not stated anywhere in the documentation. Relying on this behaviour is a bug. If you want an ordered sequence you *must* sort the result. You can then easily imagine that there is no way to make `iglob` return a sorted result since it does not even have all results available.

If memory is really a problem then you have two choices:

1. Drop the "aplhabetical order" requirement and just use `iglob`.
2. Sort the data using some kind of "bucket sorting", keeping most of the data on disk and loading it into RAM in chunks (such techniques are explained in The Art of Computer Programming, Book 3). This approach will make your program slower and probably much harder to write. But if you really can not hold all the filenames in RAM then you'll have to save them on disk eventually.